# Iterating Over Request Line In C

Tags: c, http, web, get, httprequest

I'm attempting to iterate over a HTTP request line to determine its legitimacy. Ultimately, my server will not know what the request line will look like or how long it will be.  Assume a legitimate request is exactly like the one below.  Note that it has only two spaces, one ?, and no internal ". I need to iterate through the request line to check for the spaces at a minimum, but since I won't know its length in advance and don't want to declare an array of arbitrary size, it's going to be kind of like reading braille. Below was my attempt to discover whether it contained two spaces or something else.  It returned an error that stated I was comparing ints and pointers. I've been told that, in addition to iteration, the following functions may be helpful: strchr, strcpy, strncmp, strncpy, strstr. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
int main ()
{
    const char* line = "GET /path/script.cgi?field1=value1&field2=value2 HTTP/1.0";

    parse(line);

}

bool parse(const char* line)
{   
    int spaces = 0;
    int n = strlen(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == " ")
            spaces++;
    }
    if (spaces == 2)
    {
        printf("Only 2 spaces!\n");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Illegal request! More than two spaces! Hacker! Hacker! Help!\n");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: In `if (line[i] == " ")` you are comparing a single character `line[i]` with a character string `" "`.  That's a cause for complaint.  You can use one of `if (line[i] == " "[0])` (not sensible) or `if (line[i] == ' ')` (sensible) to fix the problem.  It is important to understand the difference between character constants in single quotes and string constants in double quotes.  Also, you should declare `parse()` before you call it; the compiler assumes the return type is `int` (if it accepts it at all) when you don't do that.

Comment: Note that (with the fixed comparison), you'd accept `" GET/path/wotnot HTTP/1.0"` as valid because there are two spaces in it, even though it is not valid. You need a more sensitive test, I believe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, Johnathan! I'm honestly surprised that it caused an issue. I haven't worked with too many languages, and I never realised C knew the difference between " " and ' '. I'll look up the underlying concept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space char with single quotes, not double quotes